# If I cannot draw a world in a truth tree in modal logic does that mean that no other worlds exist for that statement?

Tags: reference-request, modal-logic, truth-tree

Suppose I have a truth tree for a modal logic statement that is closed or is open but for which I cannot continue drawing worlds, does that mean that there are no other accessible worlds in that modal logic for that statement?

I assume there are no other worlds, but perhaps my view on the accessible relation is limited by my use of truth trees.

This question is related to another one I had about a particular statement in modal system K where I was not sure if I could find a counterexample given a completed, but open truth tree: [What is the counterexample in modal system K for "⬜A ➡A"?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/57195/29944)

I am interested in references providing an answer so I could quote them later and get more detailed information on this question.

Comment: Not very clear... The completeness theorem for truth trees is based on the lemma that an *open* branch that is "finished" (i.e. no more rules are applicable) is *satisfiable*. Amd a closed branch (i.e. one with a contradiction) is obviously unsatisfiable.

Comment: "no other accessible worlds in that modal logic for that statement" - accessibility is a relation between worlds (e.g. w17 is accessible from w12), not between statements and worlds.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Would you have a reference for the completeness theorem for truth trees. I will search for it in the mean time.

Comment: @Eliran I agree that the accessibility relation is between worlds, but the truth tree is built on a statement and different statements have different trees. That is why I am associating this with a statement.

Comment: Classical logic : R.Smullyan, [First order logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=kgvhQ-oSZiUC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: S.Kripke, [Semantical Analysis of Modal Logic](http://fitelson.org/142/kripke_1.pdf).

Comment: Melvin Fitting & Richard Mendelsohn, [First-order Modal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=JMV9ZOg3KkUC&printsec=frontcover), Springer (1998)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I imagine truth trees work for classical logic, but would they also identify all the worlds in modal logic? Graham Kemp's comment on his answer makes me wonder if this is a good way to count the worlds: *"The diagram does not indicate how many (if any) worlds are accessible"*

Answer (score 3):

> Suppose I have a truth tree for a modal logic statement that is closed or is open but for which I cannot continue drawing worlds, does that mean that there are no other accessible worlds in that modal logic for that statement?

No, it merely means that you *can not infer* that there are any when constructing a proof tree.   Don't confuse a proof tree with a Frame.   A Frame is a particular set of worlds and the accessiblity relation between them.   A proof tree is simply a tool to determine if a set of statements could be satisfiable in a given system.

Comment: That makes sense, but I need a reference for this question, preferably one online so I can easily access it and get more information.